# Executing Python scripts via CGI on Apache Tomcat

Tags: python, apache, tomcat, cgi

I set up Python CGI via [this](http://lekshmideepu.blogspot.com/2013/03/configure-tomcat-7-to-run-python-cgi.html) tutorial on my Tomcat server, so I can do some file operations triggered in the browser. When I go to cgi-bin/script.py, the print statements appear in my browser. But, on the server, the file I/O operations are not being completed. Anyone know why this might be? I've tried using relative and absolute paths, as well as doing chmod 777 on my script. Code I'm trying to run:

```
print("Content-type: text/html\n\n");

count = 0
while (count < 3):     
    count = count + 1
    print("test\n")

f = open('/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/cgi/itworked.txt','w')
f.write("it worked.")
f.close()
```

I get this output in browser but no files are changed or created:

```
test
test
test
```